# Python module not found when using Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have an Angular-Flask application that I'm trying to Dockerize.
One of the Python files used is a file called **trial.py**. This file uses a module called **_trial.pyd**. When I run the project on local everything works fine. However, when I dockerize using the following code and run, it gives me error "Module _trial not found".

```
FROM node:latest as node
COPY . /APP
COPY package.json /APP/package.json
WORKDIR /APP
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
CMD ng build --base-href /static/

FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /APP/ .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Where am I going wrong? Do I need to change some path in my dockerfile?

**EDIT:**
Directory structure:

> - APP [folder with src Angular files]
> - static [folder with js files]
> - templates [folder with index.html]
> - _trial.pyd
> - app.py [Starting point of execution]
> - Dockerfile
> - package.json
> - requirements.txt
> - trial.py

app.py calls trial.py (successfully).

trial.py needs _trial.pyd. I try to call it using **import _trial**.

It works fine locally, but when I dockerize it, i get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "app.py", line 7, in
>
> ```
> from trial import *
> ```
>
> File "/root/trial.py", line 15, in
>
> import _trial
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_trial'

The commands run are:

```
docker image build -t prj .

docker container run --publish 5000:5000 --name prj prj
```

**UPDATE**
It is able to recognize other .py files but not .pyd module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!
The issue was that I was using .pyd files in a Linux container. However, it seems that Linux doesn't support .pyd files. This is why it was not able to detect the _trial.pyd module. I had to generate a shared object (.so) file (i.e. _trial.so) and it worked fine.

EDIT: The .so file was generated on a Linux system by me. Generating .so on Windows and then using it in a Linux container gives "invalid ELF header" error.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be due to the following reasons

**Path**

Make sure the required file is in the pythonpath. It sounds like you have done that so probably not this one.

**Debug Mode**

If you are working with a debug mode you will need to rename this module "_trail.pyd" to "_trail_d.pyd"

**Missing DLL**

The .pyd file may require a dll or other dependency that is not available and cant be imported due to that. there are tools such as depends.exe or [this](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) that allow you to find what is required

**Name Space Issue**

If there was a file already called "_trail.py" in the python path that could create unwanted behavior.

Comment: Yes. How can I change my path so that this file is detected. Everything has been copied to APP folder so shouldn't it find this file automatically?