# Python module not found with docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-poetry

I try to bring a Python code into a docker image. For this I build:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN pip install -U pip poetry==1.1.13
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./copilot-prototype .
RUN poetry export --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "/app/src/test_copilot/main.py" ]
```

My files are:

```
config.yaml
poetry.lock
pyproject.toml
README.md
requirements.txt
src/test_copilot/main.py
src/test_copilot/__init__.py
....
```

but everytime I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/test_copilot/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import test_copilot.gpt.api as api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_copilot'
```

Why the module is not recognized inside the docker container on execute? From what I read the pip install will install exact this module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python module not found when using Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390400/python-module-not-found-when-using-docker)

Comment: workdir is `/app` you try to import `test_copilot` but that's in `/app/src` and you're not adding that to the PYTHONPATH anywhere.  maybe WORKDIR should be `/app/src`  ?

Comment: The current directory `.` is usually in Python's search path, but your application code is under a `src` subdirectory relative to where you are.  Does changing to `WORKDIR /app/src` help, maybe just adding this line at the end of the Dockerfile?